# Swift call IBAction method not working

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

I am using this code to trigger a button in my view controller. The button wil be used to call the emergency services. The code doesn't seem to work.

```
let busPhone = 112;

@IBAction func NoodnummerCal(sender: Any) {

    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(busPhone)") {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    }
```

When I run the app and push the button the app cashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ONGEVAL.Gewonden
>   NoodnummerCal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: From [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/Art/dwx-qs-12_2x.png) image. Look into the bottom right panel named 'console'. There you should look for things like 'reason', 'error', 'invalid', 'exception' and see what they are seeing and then search them and see if you can find answers to your questions. If you found an answer by searching for them, then delete this question. If you didn't then edit the question with the exact error and tell us what you tried by reading other answers, so we could suggest further steps...

Comment: Show the error message on the crash.

Comment: Agree with @RashwanL, what's the error?

Comment: This is what I found : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ONGEVAL.Gewonden NoodnummerCal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Assuming that the name of the project is: "ONGEVAL", since the name of the method "NoodnummerCal" matches the one you implementing, are you working in "Gewonden" view controller?

Comment: Yes I am working in "Gewonden" view controller.

Comment: Tel URLs don’t have //. Your URL should be `tel:112` And your function should be `noodNummerCal(_ sender:UIButton)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call code is working even though you´re using the old syntax. Your error is from your `@IBAction`. Remove that action and create a new one with the new syntax instead. Also below is an updated call code with the current syntax:

```
@IBAction func callButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let busPhone = 112
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(busPhone)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the app doesn't carsh but it also doesn't call.

Comment: @JensVandenEede Make sure to connect it to the button (you should see an empty circle beside the IBAction declaration, just drag it to the desired button).

Comment: Remove the old `IBAction` from your code and Storyboard and then create a new one and add the code. Have you done that?

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfk72m498pyr7di/ButtonCall.zip?dl=0) is the sample project I created that will show you how I did it and how you should. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I think it doesn't work. When I push the button nothing happens.

Comment: Did you download the test project I linked and tested it? You can zip your project and upload it to Dropbox/Google drive and I’ll take a look at it for you.

Comment: Yes I downloaded it but when I tap the button in simulator it doesnt work.

Comment: @JensVandenEede, this will not work in the simulator since you don´t have the phone app on it. You need to try it on an actual device and it will work for you. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you"ve been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Interface Builder, the button might not be Enabled.